Can not connect to joomla DB from active template directory?
Using shaper_helix3 template, I'm having hard time to connect to DB from a custom.php I placed at /templates/shaper_helix3/custom.php directory. I'm sending a parameter with some external js code and this is catch well but can't make work the db part.
Not sure what can I be missing since I know some php but I'm kind of new working with joomla.
Here is the full php script I'm trying to make work when connecting to db:
<?php

try {

    $countryId = isset($_POST['country_id']) ? (int) $_POST['country_id'] : 0;

    if ($countryId > 0) {

        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

        $query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select('zone_name')
            ->from($db->quoteName('q82fq_eshop_zones'))
            ->where($db->quoteName('country_id') . ' = ' . $db->quote($countryId));

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $comunas = $db->loadObjectList();

        $opciones = [];
        foreach ($comunas as $comuna) {
            $opciones[] = [
                'value' => $comuna->zone_name, 
                'label' => $comuna->zone_name,
            ];
        }

        echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'choices' => $opciones]);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Invalid country ID.']);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage()]);
}

?>`

Script not even fully executes since it dies with error in this line: db = JFactory::getDbo(); and I'm not getting any error details from server.
I also tried to add ddefined('_JEXEC') or die; at begging of the file but them script just dies. There are no tracket logs in joomla log file when running the script.
Is there a way to solve this so I can finally connect to db from mentioned directory?

To help debug your scripts and see error information, add these statements at the top of your script:
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Because the Joomla libraries have not been loaded by that script, it is failing when calling JFactory::getDbo() because Joomla has not been loaded in that script.
Depending on what version you're using, the code may vary, but something like this should get you started.
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

/**
 * Constant that is checked in included files to prevent direct access.
 * define() is used rather than "const" to not error for PHP 5.2 and lower
 */
define('_JEXEC', 1);

// Include the Joomla framework
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../includes/defines.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../includes/framework.php';

// Initialize the Joomla application
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

// Get the database object
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Rest of your code here...

Because you stated that your script is located in templates/shaper_helix3/custom.php, the Joomla core files are located 2 directories up, so the require statements look for defines.php and framework.php in the "includes" directory which is two directories up from the current location.
Something like this should get you started. If you look at your Joomla installations's index.php file and trace that through you should be able to come up with the necessary code.
